# ESLint: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value with @react-google-maps/api and TypeSscript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, react-google-maps-api

I'm implementing a draggable marker with @react-google-maps/api, so I create a controllable state using useState. However, when I create a `handleMarkerDrag` function, TypeScript complains about the any type, despite all params and returns being typed. Please advise.

```js
...
const [markerLoc, setMarkerLoc] = useState({
    lat: 40.730155,
    lng: -74.00451,
});

const handleMarkerDrag = (e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
    const lat: number = e.latLng!.lat();
    const lng: number = e.latLng!.lng();
    setMarkerLoc({ lat, lng });
  };
...
```

The errors thrown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like `google.maps.MapMouseEvent` isn't found

Comment: Don't think so, ESLint previously complained about 'google' namespace not being found, but I fixed it by installing '@types/google.maps'